# Не удаётся преобразовать строку из XML файла в float

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml

Начал делать платформер на Unity с сохранениями в XML файлах. Код чтения элемента root:

```
XElement root = null;
if (File.Exists(Path))
{
    root = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(Path)).Element("root");
    if (root == null)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Save loading failed");
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Save loading failed");
    return;
}
Debug.Log("Save loaded");
GenerateScene(root);
```

Код чтения атрибутов и назначения позиции:

```
foreach(XElement position in root.Elements("position"))
{
    Vector3 GameObjectPosition = Vector3.zero;
    GameObjectPosition.x = float.Parse(position.Attribute("x").Value);
    GameObjectPosition.y = float.Parse(position.Attribute("y").Value);

    Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(position.Value), GameObjectPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

При выполнении возвращает такую ошибку: Input string was not in a correct format. TryParse также возвращает ошибку. В XML файле все значения являются числами с плавающей точкой, но типа string. Пытался добавить f в конце, но не помогло

Comment: Числа с запятой или точкой? Очевидно, не совпадает формат в файле с форматом культуры по умолчанию. Выход: укажите культуру вторым параметром: `float.Parse(...Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Вместо Invariant нужно указать подходящую.

Comment: Есть ещё такой способ: `(float)position.Attribute("x")`. Документация: [XElement.Explicit Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо. Со вторым вариантом всё заработало.